# COUNTIF, VLOOKUP, and mapped references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup, countif

I need to do these using formulas, not VBA.

I have a table with data about some locations:

**TABLE 1**

| RECORD NO. | LOCATION | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Location 1 | New |
| 2 | Location 1 | Old |
| 3 | Location 2 | New |
| 4 | Location 4 | Old |
| 5 | Location 1 | New |
| 6 | Location 6 | Old |
| 7 | Location 1 | New |
| 8 | Location 2 | New |
| 9 | Location 3 | New |

If I wanted to count the number of "New" records for each location, I know I *could* do this:

**TABLE 1a**

| LOCATION | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Location 1 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 1",[Status],"New") |
| Location 2 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 2",[Status],"New") |
| Location 3 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 3",[Status],"New") |
| Location 4 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 4",[Status],"New") |
| Location 5 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 5",[Status],"New") |
| Location 6 | =COUNTIF([Location],"Location 6",[Status],"New") |

However, I have this table that collects the locations into groups:

**TABLE 2**

| LOCATION | GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| Location 1 | Group A |
| Location 2 | Group A |
| Location 3 | Group A |
| Location 4 | Group B |
| Location 5 | Group B |
| Location 6 | Group C |

And my goals are to count the number of "New" records in each group:

**TABLE 3**

| Group A | Group B | Group C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| counts | counts | counts |

I'm not sure what to do next. My head spins when I try to figure something using `COUNTIF()`, `VLOOKUP()`, or maybe a Pivot Table. I wonder if `SUMPRODUCT()` or `MMULT()` would help, but I don't understand them very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUM(N(FILTER($C$2:$C$10,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($B$2:$B$10,
 FILTER($E$2:$E$7,H$1=$F$2:$F$7))))="New"))
```

---

**Notes:** Formula needs to fill right, also ensure to change ranges and references as per your suit.

---

And If you are using **`MS365`** can use one single dynamic array formula to spill.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=BYCOL(H1:J1,LAMBDA(x,
 SUM(N(FILTER(C2:C10,ISNUMBER(
 XMATCH(B2:B10,FILTER(E2:E7,F2:F7=x))))="New"))))
```

---

Another way you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUM((XLOOKUP($B$2:$B$10,$E$2:$E$7,$F$2:$F$7)=H$1)*($C$2:$C$10="New"))
```

---

Or, Spill all at once:

[image]

---

• in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=BYCOL(H1:J1,LAMBDA(x,
 SUM((XLOOKUP($B$2:$B$10,$E$2:$E$7,$F$2:$F$7)=x)*($C$2:$C$10="New"))))
```

---

Or, use <kbd>BYCOL( )</kbd> in this way:

[image]

---

• in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=BYCOL((XLOOKUP(B2:B10,E2:E7,F2:F7)=H$1:J$1)*(C2:C10="New"),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))
```

---

You can use <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=MMULT(TOROW(A2:A10)^0,(XLOOKUP(B2:B10,E2:E7,F2:F7)=H$1:J$1)*(C2:C10="New"))
```

---

Or,

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10)^0,(XLOOKUP(B2:B10,E2:E7,F2:F7)=H$1:J$1)*(C2:C10="New"))
```

---

Or,

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:A10^0),(INDEX(F2:F7,MATCH(B2:B10,E2:E7,0))=H1:J1)*(C2:C10="New"))
```

---

You can also use <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> to achieve the desired output.

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert both the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Locationtbl` & `Grouptbl`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    //Source Tables --> Locationtbl & Grouptbl
    LocationSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Locationtbl"]}[Content],
    GroupSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Grouptbl"]}[Content],
    
    //Merging both the tables using Left Join
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(LocationSource, {"LOCATION"}, GroupSource, {"LOCATION"}, "GroupSource", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    
    //Expanding the records
    #"Expanded Grouptbl" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "GroupSource", {"GROUP"}, {"GROUP"}),
    
    //Grouping by Group Column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Grouptbl", {"GROUP"}, {{"All", each _, type table [STATUS=text, GROUP=text]}}),
    
    //Added Custom Index Column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    
    //Removed unwanted columns
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    
    //Expanding Columns
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"STATUS", "GROUP", "Index"}, {"STATUS", "GROUP", "Index"}),

    //Removing the Status which are old
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Custom", each ([STATUS] = "New")),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"STATUS"}),
    
    //Pivoting the column to get the counts.
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[GROUP]), "GROUP", "Index", List.Count)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Excel file can be downloaded from **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckBRVx9PN5Sup5I3K?e=kDhIK8)**

---

Comment: Thanks; the first one works really well for my sample tables. Now I have to make it work with my REAL tables.

In the real Table 1, have to filter three columns, not one. I'm now familiarizing myself with FILTER to see if I can modify your formula.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson glad to know it worked for you. =)

Comment: Acutally, I'm still a little lost. Your first answer works for a single criterion. How would I change it if the table had a Date column, and it had to be filtered for dates older than today?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson do you have an excel file with some sample data showing expected output? Assuming based on date column change it this part to `="New"` to `<=TODAY()`

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson if you are using the first formula then it needs to be like this : `=SUM(N(FILTER($C$2:$C$13,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($B$2:$B$13,
 FILTER($E$2:$E$7,H$1=$F$2:$F$7))))<TODAY()))`

Answer (score 0):

Mayukh's answers were helpful, but as it happens I found a simpler way.

In Table 2, I assigned a name to the groups of location. The cells containing "Location 4" and "Location 5" were named "Group2", for instance.

COUNTIF(B2:B10,Group2) returns an array; each cell of which is the Count for that location. In the above example, the first cell is the Count of Location 4, and the next is the count of Location 5.

This is interesting, but now I need to add up the counts. Fortunately, SUMPRODUCT is happy to take an array as its argument.

SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10,) gave me what I needed.